# @autoreleasepool make errors

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I tried compile program with MagicalRecord and I have error

I[image: print screen from compilation] do not know how resolve this problem

in older sdk every thing is ok.

Comment: just tested @autoreleasepool {} on first generation iPhone running iOS3.0 - works without problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need the special case. `@autoreleasepool` will work for all iOS versions. this is a compiler feature, not an iOS feature. this is assuming you are using xcode 4.2. If you have an earlier version of xcode, `@autoreleasepool` is not available.