# What iOS version is required to use @autoreleasepool?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, version, nsautoreleasepool

When I run code using `@autorelease` keyword on iOS 4.3.x it throws this error.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_autoreleasePoolPush
  Referenced from: /Users/Eonil/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/3782382E-293A-4D5E-86E6-28BE35CF6048/EonilCocoaComplementsTester.app/EonilCocoaComplementsTester
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_autoreleasePoolPush
  Referenced from: /Users/Eonil/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/3782382E-293A-4D5E-86E6-28BE35CF6048/EonilCocoaComplementsTester.app/EonilCocoaComplementsTester
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

I thought the keyword is just replacement of explicit autorelease-pool creation/deletion. Anyway it wasn't, and threw an error. Does it supported only in specific version of iOS? So where can I check the version information about this keyword?

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069570/autoreleasepool-make-errors

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to @autoreleasepool?

You can use @autoreleasepool in an app with a build target of iOS 4.3.x if you are using Xcode 4.2 and the iOS 5 SDK. Despite the [transitioning to ARC guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) stating that "ARC introduces a statement construct to the Objective-C grammar" in @autoreleasepool, which might suggest ARC is required, it goes on to say that, "This syntax is available in all Objective-C modes."

While I don't think that's particularly clear documentation, what this means is that you can use the @autoreleasepool syntax both with and without ARC—if you're using the iOS 5 SDK.

Comment: @autoreleasepool does not require ARC. see.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7950583/927947

Comment: Ah interesting, have updated my answer to correct this and to highlight the key parts of the linked documentation that on first reading could be misinterpreted... like I did. :)

Answer (score 3):

just tested @autoreleasepool {} on first generation iPhone running iOS3.0 - works without problem

Comment: That's true, just tried on my iPhone 3G iOS 3.1.3, no problems

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a bug in the Simulator.

Setting the deployment target to 4.2 instead of 4.2.1 worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I had the exact same issue and this resolved it for me as well